# How to answer two requests in socket io and without delay

Tags: node.js, websocket, server, socket.io, client

When ‏I receive a request from the client and my response is a large number of records, and at the same time another request comes to the server, the second request is answered with a little delay. In fact, the socketIO  cannot send two responses to the client at the same time. Does anyone know what is the solution to my problem?

I received request by sockei.on
And send response with socket.emit
I have server with express and socket io

Answer (score 0):

Socket messages (server to client) are not "responses".

There are no "responses" in realtime socket programming.

They are commands in both directions.

That's all there is.

1. A command **arrives from a client** saying "I need the latest map". The client->server command might be say "need-new-map" (or it could just be a single digit, or whatever, any token meaning that command).
2. There's no "response", it's just an incoming command from a client.
3. Your server starts a **background process** building the map; let's say building a map takes 100 seconds as an example. On the process, you **make a note** of which client it was (let's say, client #11007).
4. As it happens, another command arrives from a client (perhaps the same client or a different client, doesn't matter)
5. As it happens, another command arrives from a client (perhaps the same client or a different client, doesn't matter)
6. Later, the process mentioned in (2) is complete. The process does these things: (i) Check if client #11007 **is still connected**. (ii) if so, send a command to that client. The command would be perhaps "new-map" followed by the binary data of the map.

If in the client you're "listening for a response", you have completely misunderstood the basic paradigm of realtime comms.

> In fact, the socketIO cannot send two responses to the client at the same time

Every communication from the server to a client, is a command.  They might look like these examples ...

```
set-email example@example.com
ask-user-for-creds
new-table-data . . . various data, perhaps as json . . .
new-url http ...
log-out-the-user
```

and so on.

server->client and client->server commands are totally unrelated.

Clients never wait for a response. Clients are puppets that act on the commands sent to them as server->client commands.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what I did, the client sends its request to the server and after the response is ready, the server sends the response to the client. The problem is that if several clients send requests to the server at the same time, the server will send them to the client in a queue when their answers are ready, and the last client may receive the answer with a long delay. How can I manage this issue that all clients get the answer you want in real time.